# Made IntPtr from myStruct in c#, but c++ dll is expecting a myStruct*, not an IntPtr

Tags: c#, c++-cli

In my c# main, I did

```
        myStruct ret_vals;
        IntPtr ptr = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(Marshal.SizeOf(ret_vals));

        Marshal.StructureToPtr(ret_vals, ptr, false);
```

MyStruct has a pointer to another structure in it. According to Intelllisense (compile error) my C++ dll's function is expecting a pointer to MyStruct, not an IntPtr. The following won't compile

```
       DoAT.atClass1 cl = new DoAT.atClass1();

      cl.read_file( ptr);
```

Incidentally, my c++ function is declared as

```
    public ref class atClass1
{
    public:
          int read_file(MyStruct & ret_vals)    ;

};
```

Advice appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried "unsafe" to get a struct-pointer?

Comment: If your C# code is accessing a managed C++/CLI assembly, why are you using unmanaged memory?

Comment: @Marc -- says I can't get a pointer to a managed type

Comment: @tdb:thanks, it's all new to me so I'm struggling, but I will try using managed as suggested

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't use `&` when using references in C++/CLI, like you would in regular C++, but rather `%`. This means you'll have to define your C++/CLI function as such:

```
public ref class atClass1
{
public:
    int read_file(MyStruct % ret_vals);
};
```

That way you can just call your function using .NET reference parameters:

```
DoAT.atClass1 cl = new DoAT.atClass1();
cl.read_file(ref ret_vals);
```

No need for the `Marshal` class!

Comment: Of course that also means that MyStruct should be a managed value type. The general point here is that the public members of a managed type should be .NET-friendly, and that means no C++ pointers, references, unmanaged types, etc.

Comment: @user1610015 -- right you are as I just found out while building my c# main! I'm rather stuck at making this conversion so I'll start a new thread as my original question of this thread has been answered. thanks!

Comment: @antonijn: When I used your idea above, my c++ compiled fine.But in my c# driver app, it could not access p_vars which is a member of ret_vals. p_vars is an instance of a public structure. Also my call to read_file ("c:\\a.h5",ref ret_vals) continues to not compile, saying it has invalid arguments. It is expecting a string and a ref to DoAt.MyStruct which is exactly what I'm delivering it, no?